# Android native code: AMotionEvent_getHistorySize always 0?

Tags: android, native-code, native-methods

All,

I'm writing a native application for Android and i'm stuck trying to acquire historical data for motion events. It seems that AMotionEvent_getHistorySize() returns always 0, but if i query the 0'th element for X and Y I seem to get the valid data (current X and Y).

so is there any way I could get historical data or is it just plain broken..?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we gave up, eventually. The same behavior has been observed on a number of android devices and we eventually implemented history by ourselves.